# appendQueryParameter vs. selection arguments

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am wodnering if it makes a difference if one specifies selection arguments in the URI or as corresponding parameters? E.g.

```
Uri.Builder builder = Something.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon(); 
builder.appendQueryParameter("someColumn", "someValue");
Uri uri = builder.build();

getContext().getContentResolver().select(uri, null, null);
```

versus

```
getContext().getContentResolver().select(
    Something.CONTENT_URI, 
    new String[]{"someColumn"}, 
    new String[]{"someValue"}
);
```

I guess ContentResolver internally parses and splits the URI, so it doesn't actually make a difference?

Or is the URI passed directly to the ContentProvider, so the ContentProvider needs to have appropriate URI parsing implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to figure it out myself:
Try passing e.g. Events.CALENDAR_ID as URI parameter to CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, this gives

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1714): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI parameter: calendar_id
E/AndroidRuntime(1714):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
```